# jquery-datatables-rails gem not working for update call, converting PUT request to POST request automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I created a simple rails app:
:~ rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
:~ rake db:migrate
and then edited _form.html.erb for using the DataTable Plugin:

```
<table id="users" class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
  <th>Update</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<td><div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div></td>
<td><div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div></td>
<td><div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The form works completely well when a User is created. But, when i try update User's information it returns me a routing error:
No route matches [POST] "/users/1"

For Update the call should have been PUT but it is using POST here. It only happens when I use the Gem otherwise the Update is working fine.
Please look into the following matter.

Issue Link :[here](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails/issues/51)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem. Had to work around it by using `:include_id => false` so that rails doesn't generate the hidden `:id` field, and then manually added a hidden field in one of the td's.